# Changing Table Engine in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I am using mysql and mysql workbench. I created 5 tables with innodb engine. I checked their engine and it was innodb before I insert data into them. I inserted data from 5 MyISAM tables and now my innodb tables are MyISAM. I can't change them. I used the alter table engine=innodb but it doesn't work.

Comment: Give us more details. How did you try to change engine? How did you "inserted data from 5 MyISAM tables"?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

From the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

For example, to convert a table to be an `InnoDB` table, use this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The outcome of attempting to change a table's storage engine is affected by whether the desired storage engine is available and the setting of the `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` SQL mode, as described in [Section 5.1.11](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution), “Server SQL Modes”.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution

When you create the table do you get any warning about the Engine type being unavailable?

Answer (score 25):

It's not obvious. If you edit the table and then **select the column tab** the engine widget is not immediately visible. On the upper right of the edit window you will see two down pointing chevrons. **Select the arrow once** and additional widgets will appear. In the upper right hand corner **there will now be widgets** for the schema and engine.

[image: Result]

Comment: I edited the picture to put pointers and numbered 1 and 2 to show the sequence of action.