# How to search multiple columns in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

How to search multiple column, this code search single column , please customise my code

```
$keywords= "search keywords";
$keywords= htmlspecialchars($keywords);    
$keywords= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $keywords);
$countSql_s = "SELECT *, MATCH(website) AGAINST ('%".$keywords."%') AS score FROM search WHERE MATCH(website) AGAINST ('%".$keywords."%') ORDER BY score DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your "WHERE" to include a check for each column, like this:

```
... WHERE MATCH(website) AGAINST('%".$keywords."%') > 5
AND MATCH(username) AGAINST('%".$keywords."%') > 5
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your table as:

```
ALTER TABLE --table name-- ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_search (column1,colum2,column3);
```

Then you can search like this:

```
MATCH (column1,column2) AGAINST ('%".$keywords."%')
```

Comment: i have small doubt what is meant by fulltext_search @ Jeremy Gurr

Comment: FULLTEXT is index for search.To use full text you need to define he columns as FULLTEXT

Comment: i have another doubt, how to change my db ENGINE=InnoDB into ENGINE=MyISAM

Comment: r u using phpmyadmin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240977/changing-table-engine-in-mysql